# Function differential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, differential-forms

The task is to find following function differential: 
$$f(x,y)=x^y+y^x.$$
Am I right saying that 
$$df=(yx^{y-1}+\ln y\cdot y^x)dx+(xy^{x-1}+\ln x \cdot x^y)dy?$$

Not sure about it, as I've missed several lessons on this topic..
Will appreciate any responses

Comment: That seems fine to me :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is entirely correct. For future reference [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%28x%5Ey-y%5Ex%29) is entirely capable of finding the same solution, allowing you to quickly verify your own solution. Scroll to the bottom to find the desired answer under the heading 'Differential'.

Comment: Thanks for your response, will try that)